# Is there a robocopy switch for gathering timestamps longer than 260 characters?

Tags: windows, powershell, date, robocopy

I am attempting to extract the **date last modified** from the files in a Windows directory.  Here is my basic script:

```
Function Get-FolderItem {
    

    [cmdletbinding(DefaultParameterSetName='Filter')]
    Param (
        [parameter(Position=0,ValueFromPipeline=$True,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$True)]
        [Alias('FullName')]
        [string[]]$Path = $PWD,
        [parameter(ParameterSetName='Filter')]
        [string[]]$Filter = '*.*',    
        [parameter(ParameterSetName='Exclude')]
        [string[]]$ExcludeFile,              
        [parameter()]
        [int]$MaxAge,
        [parameter()]
        [int]$MinAge
    )
    Begin {
        $params = New-Object System.Collections.Arraylist
        $params.AddRange(@("/L","/E","/NJH","/NDL","/BYTES","/FP","/NC","/XJ","/R:0","/W:0","T:W","/TS","/UNILOG:c:\temp\test.txt"))
        #params.AddRange(@("/L","/S","/NJH","/BYTES","/FP","/NC","/NDL","/TS","/XJ","/R:0","/W:0"))
        If ($PSBoundParameters['MaxAge']) {
            $params.Add("/MaxAge:$MaxAge") | Out-Null
        }
        If ($PSBoundParameters['MinAge']) {
            $params.Add("/MinAge:$MinAge") | Out-Null
        }
    }
    Process {
        ForEach ($item in $Path) {
            Try {
                $item = (Resolve-Path -LiteralPath $item -ErrorAction Stop).ProviderPath
                If (-Not (Test-Path -LiteralPath $item -Type Container -ErrorAction Stop)) {
                    Write-Warning ("{0} is not a directory and will be skipped" -f $item)
                    Return
                }
                If ($PSBoundParameters['ExcludeFile']) {
                    $Script = "robocopy `"$item`" NULL $Filter $params /XF $($ExcludeFile  -join ',')"
                } Else {
                    $Script = "robocopy `"$item`" NULL $Filter $params"
                }
                Write-Verbose ("Scanning {0}" -f $item)
                Invoke-Expression $Script | Out-Null
                get-content "c:\temp\test.txt" | ForEach {
                    Try {
                        If ($_.Trim() -match "^(?<Children>\d+)\s(?<FullName>.*)") {
                           $object = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
                                FullName = $matches.FullName
                                Extension = $matches.fullname -replace '.*\.(.*)','$1'
                                FullPathLength = [int] $matches.FullName.Length
                                FileHash = Get-FileHash -LiteralPath "\\?\$($matches.FullName)" |Select -Expand Hash
                                Created = ([System.IO.FileInfo] $matches.FullName).creationtime
                                LastWriteTime = ([System.IO.FileInfo] $matches.FullName).LastWriteTime
                                Characters = (Get-Content -LiteralPath "\\?\$($matches.FullName)" | Measure-Object -ignorewhitespace -Character).Characters
                                Owner = (Get-ACL $matches.Fullname).Owner
                                
                            } 
                            $object.pstypenames.insert(0,'System.IO.RobocopyDirectoryInfo')
                            Write-Output $object
                        } Else {
                            Write-Verbose ("Not matched: {0}" -f $_)
                        }
                    } Catch {
                        Write-Warning ("{0}" -f $_.Exception.Message)
                        Return
                    }
                }
            } Catch {
                Write-Warning ("{0}" -f $_.Exception.Message)
                Return
            }
        }
    }
}

 $a = Get-FolderItem "C:\TargetDirectory\Folder" | Export-Csv -Path C:\Temp\output.csv -Encoding Unicode
```

The script extracts the **date last modified** of filepaths less than 260 characters.  It returns a nonsense date of **1600-12-31 4:00:00 PM** for files longer than 260 characters. Here is the line that is not working:

`LastWriteTime = ([System.IO.FileInfo] $matches.FullName).LastWriteTime`

My first attempt to solve this problem was to find a command that began with **Get-** because such commands were useful in extracting filehashes, filepaths, character counts and owner names of files longer than 260 characters.  For example:

- `Owner = (Get-ACL $matches.Fullname).Owner`
- `Characters = (Get-Content -LiteralPath "\\?\$($matches.FullName)" | Measure-Object-ignorewhitespace -Character).Characters`
- `FileHash = Get-FileHash -LiteralPath "\\?\$($matches.FullName)" |Select -Expand Hash`

`Get-Date` however seemed to be about getting the current date.

In my second attempt, I went back to Boe Prox's original blogpost on this script and noticed that his script had two components that were missing from mine:

- a robocopy switch `/TS`
- `Date = [datetime]$matches.Date`

I added to my script however doing so return an error: `WARNING: Cannot convert null to type "System.DateTime".`  I rechecked the file in the directory, and it clearly has a date.

I reexamined the documentation on **Get-Date** and tried

`Date = Get-Date -Format o | ForEach-Object { $matches -replace ":", "." }`

However, this returned `WARNING: Cannot convert value "2018/03/05 18:06:54  C:TargetDirectory\Folder\Temp.csv to type "System.IO.FileInfo". Error: " Illegal characters in path."`

(N.B. In other posts, people have suggested changing the server settings to permit the existence of files longer than 260 characters.  This is not an option for me because I do not have access to the servers.)

Comment: `Get-Date -Format o` returns the current date formatted as an ISO8601 timestamp - nothing more. `Get-ItemPropertyValue -LiteralPath "\\?\$($matches.FullName)" LastWriteTime` should get you the LastWriteTime value of the file

Comment: Hi Mathias.  Your answer has solved my problem - maybe even saved my job. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Once you hit 260 characters in the path, you hit the old [Windows MAX_PATH limitation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/maximum-file-path-limitation?tabs=powershell). In order to get around that, you have to prepend your path with `\\?\`.

In your code above, you do that for `Characters` and `FileHash` but you don't do that when retrieving `LastWriteTime`. e.g. Changing the path to this will work:

```
Created = ([System.IO.FileInfo] "\\?\$($matches.FullName)").creationtime
LastWriteTime = ([System.IO.FileInfo] "\\?\$($matches.FullName)").LastWriteTime
```

The alternative way is to use the `Get-ChildItem` cmdlet along with `\\?\` prepended to the path to retrieve most of the fields you want without having to query it multiple times:

```
get-content "c:\temp\test.txt" | ForEach {
    Try {
        If ($_.Trim() -match "^(?<Children>\d+)\s(?<FullName>.*)") {
        
            $file = Get-ChildItem "\\?\$($matches.FullName)"
        
            $object = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
                FullName = $file.FullName
                Extension = $file.Extension
                FullPathLength = $file.FullName.Length
                FileHash = Get-FileHash -LiteralPath "\\?\$($matches.FullName)" |Select -Expand Hash
                Created = $file.CreationTime
                LastWriteTime = $file.LastWriteTime
                Characters = (Get-Content -LiteralPath "\\?\$($matches.FullName)" | Measure-Object -ignorewhitespace -Character).Characters
                Owner = (Get-ACL $matches.Fullname).Owner                                
            }
            $object.pstypenames.insert(0,'System.IO.RobocopyDirectoryInfo')
            Write-Output $object
        } Else {
            Write-Verbose ("Not matched: {0}" -f $_)
        }
    } Catch {
        Write-Warning ("{0}" -f $_.Exception.Message)
        Return
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and for what looks like a faster way to run the script.  I won't be able to test until next week.

Comment: I hope this isn't a dumb question, but where do I place `$file = Get-ChildItem "\\?\$($matches.FullName)"`?

Comment: Not a dumb question at all. It would go just inside your `If ($_.Trim() ...` statement, just before you create your `$object`.

Comment: I've tried several different placements of the `$file = Get-ChildItem "\\?\$($matches.FullName)"`.  If I put it after or before `-match "^(?<Children>\d+)\s(?<FullName>.*)"` I get the error `unexpected token '$file' in expression`. Also tried eliminating the `match` statement ( because I thought your `getchilditem` and the `match` statements seem to do the same thing) - but got the same unexpected token error.  Could you maybe write those lines out in full?

Comment: @oymonk I have updated the code to better explain where it goes.

Comment: Hi @HAL9256: thanks for your work. I was getting the error `WARNING: Cannot find drive. A drive with the name '2020/09/09 17 does not exist` (the date has replaced the filename?) but I could get rid of this error by commenting out the line extracting characters and owner.  The other problem is that the output csv has no data. Even though I can't get this to work, I'm going to vote up your answer because of the first information you provided `Created = ([System.IO.FileInfo] "\\?\$($matches.FullName)").creationtime`.